# @AllArgsConstructor of Lombok doesn't work

Tags: java, lombok

Today i faced with Lombok issue what annotation @AllArgsConstructor doesn't work. I have 1 superclass for my entities:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class BaseEntity {
    protected int id;
}
```

And also some child classes, for example User:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class User extends BaseEntity{
    @Email
    @NotNull
    private String mail;
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$")
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+")
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+")
    @NotNull
    private String surname;
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate date;
    private Float currentBalance;
    private String mobile;
    private String street;
    private String accommodationNumber;
    private String flatNumber;
}
```

And, for example, in such service method i try to build user and return it:

```
 @Override
    public User getUserByCredentials(String mail, String password) {
        User user = null;
        Connection connection = connectionPool.getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_USER_QUERY);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, mail);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                user = new User(resultSet.getInt("id"), resultSet.getString("mail"), resultSet.getString("password"),
                        resultSet.getString("name"), resultSet.getString("surname"), resultSet.getDate("date").toLocalDate(),
                        resultSet.getFloat("balance"), resultSet.getString("mobile"),
                        resultSet.getString("street"), resultSet.getString("accommodation_number"),
                        resultSet.getString("flat_number"));
            }
            return user;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.warn("SQLException while getting user. Most likely request is wrong");
            return null;
        } finally {
            connectionPool.closeConnection(connection);
        }
    }
```

But, as a result, i got error, that i don't have appropriate constructor
[IDEA error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQzuF.png)
Note, that it's spring-boot project and my dependency is:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @SuperBuilder for this constructor like this :

```
@Override
public User getUserByCredentials(String mail, String password) {
    User user = null;
    Connection connection = connectionPool.getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_USER_QUERY);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, mail);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            user = User.builder()
            .id(resultSet.getInt("id"))
            .mail(resultSet.getString("mail"))
            .password(resultSet.getString("password"))
            .name(resultSet.getString("name"))
            .surname(resultSet.getString("surname"))
            .date(resultSet.getDate("date").toLocalDate())
            .currentBalance(resultSet.getFloat("balance"))
            .mobile(resultSet.getString("mobile"))
            .street(resultSet.getString("street"))
            .accommodationNumber(resultSet.getString("accommodation_number"))
            .flatNumber(resultSet.getString("flat_number"))
            .build();
        }
        return user;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.warn("SQLException while getting user. Most likely request is wrong");
        return null;
    } finally {
        connectionPool.closeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Builder like this :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {
    private final String parentName;
    private final int parentAge;
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private final String childName;
    private final int childAge;

    @Builder
    public Child(String parentName, int parentAge, String childName, int childAge) {
        super(parentName, parentAge);
        this.childName = childName;
        this.childAge = childAge;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, and it can't automatically create all args constructor and we should use Builder annotation? And what is the meaning of this annotation? Without Builder this constructor also should work

Comment: Without Builder or SuperBuilder this constructor shoud not working.